# Save single query result as a variable

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I am not having much luck in finding what I am looking for. I have a query that returns a single Id that I want to store as a variable.  I am looking to see if there is a way to do that without using the `<cfoutput>` tag, as I guess it seems like I am not really outputting anything.

```
//declare variable
<cfset documentType = 0>

<cfquery datasource="mssql" name="GetDocType">
    Select Id
    From DocTypes 
    Where Description = 'MyType'
</cfquery>
```

I want to store the result of this query into the documentType variable.  Again, I know it seems simple, but I have not seen any examples so far that really led me in the right direction. (Disclaimer, I am a .NET developer that has been given my first ColdFusion project in years - so this might be really really basic!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, but I am not sure if it's "Best Practice".

```
<cfset documentType = GetDocType.Id>
```

Since I know I will only have one row, I figured I could just reference the column that I want without having to do any looping.

If anyone has any other ideas or better ways, then let me know!

Comment: this is how I would do it, no cfoutput needed.

Comment: It's fine. That's how one would do it. That said, *best practice* would be to not call your query "GetDocType". `GetDocType` sounds like a function, not a variable ;-)

Comment: @AdamCameron - haha, fair enough :) Thanks for the validation on my method!

Comment: Actually, you don't even need another variable.  Query GetDocType is a variable and you can get the value you want by referring to GetDocType.Id[1].  Creating another variable might improve code readability but it's one more thing for the server to process.  In conclusion, Best Practices are a matter of opinion and depend on the situation.

Comment: @DanBracuk - thanks for the info.  I think the variable declaration come from my background in a compiled language.  I think here, I was looking for more advice around - well, you 'can' do that, but it causes some massive security hole or null reference exception 30% of the time.  Agreed on the opinion part of "best practices"

Comment: Well, if your actual query uses some sort of variable (rather than a hard coded string) be sure to use [`cfqueryparam` ie bind variables](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam). It provides the usual benefits: sql injection protection and enhances performance. It also has a few other benefits, like pre-db validation, simplified list handling, etc.. Side note, if you are a C# person, you might prefer [cfscript](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/The+CFScript+language) syntax over cfml. Most (though not all) cfml tags have a cfscript equivalent.

Comment: @Leigh - I use the cfqueryparam when using not-hardcoded data.  This is actually hard coded.  But definitely good advice!

Comment: You also may think about scoping your variable. Adds a small performance boost.
<cfset VARIABLES.documentType = GetDocType.Id>

Answer (score 1):

You would want to verify that `.RecordCount` is greater than 0 and the following:

```
<cfset documentType = GetDocType.Id[1]>
```

`1` is the **record number**; I believe when not looping, that's how you access a particular row in a record set.

Comment: Not necessary. If you don't provide a row number, it'll default to the first row. If the query came back with zero rows, the variable will simply be an empty string.